# New JavaScript window in HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know in JavaScript you can use the `window.open()` to open a new window in a browser.

Is it possible to create a new window in an HTML element. So instead of creating an iframe it creates a browser or window in the HTML.

**Why not use an iframe?**
Cross domain policy, iframes can't display all websites

**Background:**
I am trying to add in a website browser to a game, this game allows modding of the ui which uses CoherentUI(Essentially the UI is HTML)

Comment: What you request is essentially a substitute for an `iframe` which skips the security measures introduced to safeguard an `iframe` - don't expect this to be feasible.

Comment: So you want the equivalent of an iframe without the security restrictions of an iframe?  If that's really what you're asking, then "no", there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do is some "readfile" script in php or any Server side language, open the Website on your own, read and parse the whole content, rewrite links if needed, ...  and echo it in some div. If you want it live and in-game you should use Ajax and jquery for example.
But i guess, you should not do this without permission of the Website owner, as you copy and use his content without mentioning a source.